# How to setup SMTP-only MTA with POSTFIX in a subdomain?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I successfully setup SMTP-only using [the guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) provided by DigitalOcean. However, this time I wanted to set it up in a subdomain. Consider this domain that I have: `http://v1.product.staging.veil-soft.com.

With the same guide I used I can't make the email working.

Here are my config:

**`main.cfg` file:**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = veil-soft.com
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = veil-soft.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

**`/etc/aliases` file:**

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
root:          eng@veil-soft.com
```

**`/etc/postfix/generic` file:**

```
root@v1.product.staging.veil-soft.com noreply@veil-soft.com
```

**`/etc/mailname` file:**

```
veil-soft.com
```

**Tried to send using the `mail` command:**

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "Testing" web@veil-soft.com
```

**And the `mail.log` produces this:**

```
Aug 11 19:57:54 hostname postfix/pickup[8245]: AA598101F08: uid=0 from=<root@veil-soft.com>
Aug 11 19:57:54 hostname postfix/cleanup[8548]: AA598101F08: message-id=<20160811235754.AA598101F08@veil-soft.com>
Aug 11 19:57:54 hostname postfix/qmgr[30043]: AA598101F08: from=<root@veil-soft.com>, size=358, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 11 19:57:54 hostname postfix/local[8553]: AA598101F08: to=<web@veil-soft.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Aug 11 19:57:54 hostname postfix/qmgr[30043]: AA598101F08: removed
Aug 11 20:00:01 hostname postfix/local[8596]: 7B19E101F15: to=<eng@veil-soft.com>, orig_to=<root@veil-soft.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "eng")
Aug 11 20:00:01 hostname postfix/qmgr[30043]: 7B19E101F15: removed
Aug 11 20:00:01 hostname postfix/local[8597]: 7C8F7101F08: to=<eng@veil-soft.com>, orig_to=<root@veil-soft.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "eng")
Aug 11 20:00:01 hostname postfix/qmgr[30043]: 7C8F7101F08: removed
```

Comment: Does "engineering" exist?

Comment: Is it correct to list the users under `/var/mail/`? If yes `engineering` is not there.

Comment: Unless you're using some kind of imap server or whatever, I believe you'll need to create a local user called `engineering` for that to work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Updated my question with correct domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using some kind of imap server or whatever, I believe you'll need to create a local user called engineering for that to work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

This line worked:

```
Aug 11 19:57:54 hostname postfix/local[8553]: AA598101F08: to=<name@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox).`
```

Is `name` a local user? Setup `engineering` the same way.

- **Update to original answer**

**Based on the revised edit by the OP and comments below, the following changes need to be made to the postfix configuration**

The problem appears to be that the server was intended to relay mail to another SMTP server for the vielsoft.com domain, but was attempting local delivery instead because of misconfiguration.

> **/etc/postfix/main.cf**
>
> mydestination = v1.product.staging.vielsoft.com
>
> myhostname = v1.product.staging.vielsoft.com
>
> **/etc/mailname**
>
> v1.product.staging.vielsoft.com

Comment: Hi I am sending an email to gerald@domain.com. This user does not exist in the server in question. Which I believe it should not. What if I want to send an email to a gmail email?

Comment: But the above line didnt deliver the email to my mailbox. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gulok That line says it did deliver the message, on the local server. So I'm guessing /var/spool/mail/user. Your main.cf says `mydestination=domain.com`  so you will receive mail for that domain and not relay it.

Comment: @Gulok It says `relay=local` so it's attempting to deliver mail locally, not relay it to another server as you'd expect if it were going to gmail... can you please use proper domain names in your examples and logs? I feel the info is inaccurate. If a message is going to gmail it will show something like `relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`

Comment: Sure I will update the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Gulok Ok, based on what I see my instructions and comments stand true.

Comment: BTW, engineering does exist in my separate mail server. I have a working mail server for vielsoft.com, since the box is just a subdomain I also used vielsoft.com. Is that something correct?

Comment: @Gulok You cannot set vielsoft.com as mydestination or mailname, etc... otherwise the server will attempt to deliver the mail to a local mailbox rather than relay it to the correct server for vielsoft.com.

Comment: Which I should set it to `v1.product.staging.vielsoft.com`? +1 for the effort you have put on this thread.

Comment: If that's it's hostname, it might be appropriate. Really you can assign any domain name to it that you want especially if you're only sending mail out. If you want it to receive mail and relay it, you'll have to setup stuff in DNS, etc... so that it's an MX for a domain, then set it up to receive for that domain. The domain can be  v1.product.staging.vielsoft.com if you want.